# Mesylation of cyanohydrins

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, grignard-reagent

Is it possible to add methane sulfonyl chloride to benzaldehyde cyanohydrin, or add toluene sulfonyl chloride to form the tosylate group on the alcohol and then perfom a grignard reaction on the nitrile to form an imine? Or more succinctly do mesylate/tosylate sulphonyl chlorides react with nitriles as they do with amines.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, according to Kiritsis et al. [[1](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.carres.2013.11.001)] it is possible to mesylate cyanohydrins.

The paper by Bracco et al. [[2](https://doi.org/10.1039/C6OB00934D)] has a number of relevant examples such as protection of the cyanohydrin by *O*-silylation followed by Grignard addition and *O*-triflation followed by Suzuki coupling of the triflate with arylboronic acid. It also shows that the −OH group may also be acetylated and the tetrahydropyranyl or *t*-butyl ether can be formed.

#### References

1. Kiritsis, C.; Manta, S.; Dimopoulou, A.; Parmenopoulou, V.; Gkizis, P.; Balzarini, J.; Komiotis, D. Stereoselective Facile Synthesis of 2′-Spiro Pyrimidine Pyranonucleosides via Their Key Intermediate 2′-*C*-Cyano Analogues. Evaluation of Their Bioactivity. *Carbohydrate Research* **2014**, 383, 50–57. DOI: [10.1016/j.carres.2013.11.001](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.carres.2013.11.001).
2. Bracco, P.; Busch, H.; von Langermann, J.; Hanefeld, U. Enantioselective Synthesis of Cyanohydrins Catalysed by Hydroxynitrile Lyases – a Review. *Org. Biomol. Chem.* **2016**, 14 (27), 6375–6389. DOI: [10.1039/C6OB00934D](https://doi.org/10.1039/C6OB00934D).